# Navigate to Detail page of the record not to Feed page

Tags: visualforce, salesfoce

I have the  following scenario please help me out:

I have a page we have used it for global actions. On  click on the button on my page, i like to do the following things.

- On click on button, if the data inserted successfully, need to navigate to detail page of the record in the console view. When i tried, it is showing Feed page by default, but client expecting the destination page to be Detail page of that record in the console view.

Here is my code:

```
          <apex:inputField Value="{!workInst.agf__Severity_Level__c}" required="true"/>
           <apex:inputField Value="{!workInst.agf__Subject__c}" required="true"/>

         <apex:inputField Value="{!workInst.agf__Details_and_Steps_to_Reproduce__c}" required="true"/>
          <apex:inputField Value="{!workInst.agf__Details__c}" required="true"/>
      <!--    <apex:inputField Value="{!workInst.agf__Product_Tag__c}" required="true"/>
          <apex:inputField Value="{!workInst.agf__Assignee__c}" required="true"/> -->
   </apex:pageBlockSection>
   <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Create" oncomplete="window.top.location='/console'; return false" />
 </apex:pageBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

When we use onComplete attribute of commandbutton, it change the VF Engine mode to **partial page update** but here you have not indicated any components ID to update partially. So you need to define **rerender** attribute with associated id.